# Why did I lose the game?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So I have a saved game on 1.1.1453. If I unpause the game, I lose a day later. As far as I can tell I didn't die. I have 3 sons, one of them is my heir. No losing wars that could suddenly claim all my land or anything.

Any ideas? Is the game simply over on 2.1.1453?

(It's in german, I can translate anything if you ask for it in the comments).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I believe you only get Steam Achievements if you are in "Ironman" mode.

Comment: @StevenBurnap good to know. Found out what seems to be the reason for losing. Guess I have to play more agressive if I want to become ruler of the world in just 400 years ;)

Comment: NO! I JUST LOST THE GAME!

Comment: If you want to dish out 10 USD, paradox released an official save converter so you can continue your playthrough in EU4.

Comment: @TotallyN0tABot meh, second game ever, for free maybe, but not for $10. But thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I've found a little part in the [wiki beginners guide](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Beginner%27s_guide) stating

> CKII is a sandbox game and has no strict winstate. As long as at least one landed member of your dynasty survives (of at least the rank of count), the game will continue until 1453 and at the end you will get the same dynasty score screen (comparing your dynasty to some historical dynasties) you would get if you had resigned earlier. There are achievements that can give goals to strive for, but other than that players must choose for themselves where the emergent gameplay will take them.

Which I didn't spot earlier because it doesn't say so on the [game over wiki page](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Game_over).

(I hadn't seen that when asking, but it seems to be the solution.)

Comment: Yeah, I was about to post this. The game ends in 1453, unless you edit the game files.

Comment: @MichaelCampbell how do I edit the game files?

Comment: You can edit the end date it in defines.txt in the common folder. This video should help, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GoFIE83mhyU

Answer (score 2):

A game of CK2 ends when

- no person of your dynasty could inherit and your House goes into an end.
- you reach the year 1453 (which is your case here).